# Dymola DAE solver

Tags: ode, modelica, dymola

I am trying to figure out the steps required by Dymola in order to solve the Modelica code. By reading some reference papers and book, I understood that Dymola:

1. Translates the Modelica code into a hybrid DAE (flattening).
2. Manipulates the DAE in order to convert it into ODE form (index reduction and other techniques).
3. Uses DASSL algorithm.

My question is: why does Dymola need to used DASSL to solve the ODE? Shouldn't be enough to use a general ODE solver such as BDF or Runge-Kutta?

Thank you in advance for your attention.
All the Best,

Alessandro

Comment: Short answer: It's more efficient. A detailed answer is given by Francois Cellier in his book "Continuous System Simulation", Chapter 8.4 (DASSL)

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for the comment. I've actually read that chapter, but my doubt is: How can DASSL solve a ODE since it is a DAE solver?
If you tell me that DASSL can solve also ODE, then everything makes sense and is logic.

Comment: ODEs are a sub-set of DAEs; basically an ODE is der(x)=f(x) and a DAE is g(der(x),x)=0. So by setting g(der(x),x)=der(x)-f(x) an ODE is transformed to a DAE - and thus Dassl can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Dymola supports several integration algorithms, including RK. But DASSL is a good default. Also note that some problems cannot be reduced to ODE form.

Answer (score 0):

Index reduction "throws away" constraint information by replacing the original equations with their derivatives.

In theory this does not matter much since the derivative equations have these lost identities as conserved quantities. However, numerical integration introduces drift that may remove the state from the manifold of consistent states of the DAE. Of course the original equations can be remembered, and the additional "hidden" constraints can be constructed. One has to be careful in projecting the state back to the manifold of consistent states to not destroy the consistency and order of the integration method.

This can be ameliorated by not reducing to the index-0 ODE but stopping at the index-1 DAE stage so that there is less differentiation of the original equations. The resulting numerical integration then has essentially the complexity of an implicit RK method resp. implicit multi-step method.

For the index-1 system one would then need to use a DAE solver like DASSL.

Comment: That is not the case for the index reduction in Dymola, since the state-equations are preserved. For the theory see:
http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0914043